# Problem on atomic sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. Assume that there exists a set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $0 < \mu(A) <  \infty$ and for any subset $B \subset A$, $B \in \mathcal{F}$ we have that either 
 $ \mu(B) \geq \frac{9}{10}\mu(A)$ or  $ \mu(B) \leq \frac{1}{10}\mu(A)$.

I need to show that $A$ contains an atomic subset.

Recall that a set $E \in \mathcal{F}$ is called an atom if for any measurable subset $F\subset E$  we will have either $\mu(F) =0$ or $\mu(F) = \mu(E)$.

I am stuck at this problem for quite sometime now. I was trying to prove this by contradiction, but can not find a suitable way to use the inequalities.

Any kind of help/comment/hint is more than welcome !

Comment: By “finite measure space,” do you mean that $X$ contains finitely many elements, or that $\mu(X)<\infty$?

Comment: I meant that $\mu(X) < \infty$. But the result holds even if we only have that $\mu(A) <  \infty$. I have edited the post, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$c = \inf \left\lbrace \mu(B) : B \in \mathcal{F}, B \subset A, \mu(B) \geqslant \frac{9}{10}\mu(A) \right\rbrace.$$

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, choose a $B_n\in\mathcal{F}$, $B_n\subset A$, with $$c\leqslant \mu(B_n) \leqslant c + 2^{-n}.$$

What can you say about

$$B = \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n\;?$$

Comment: Since $\mu$ is continuous from above, we will get that $\mu(B) = c$. Is this true ? Then if we pick any $C \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $C \subset B$ and $0<\mu(C) <\mu (B)$, then we must have that $\mu(C) \leq \frac{1}{10}\mu(A)$. Similarly, we will also get that $\mu(B\setminus C) \leq \frac{1}{10}\mu(A)$, which is impossible since $\mu(B\setminus C) = \mu(B) - \mu(C) \geq \frac{8}{10}\mu(A)$. Is my argument right ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. You need to give a reason why $\mu(B) = c$, that is, why $\mu\left(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^N B_n\right) \geqslant c$ for all $N$ (induction; you need to show $\mu(B),\mu(B') \geqslant \frac{9}{10}\mu(A) \Rightarrow \mu(B\cap B') \geqslant \frac{9}{10}\mu(A)$), then the rest is as you said.

Comment: Okay, i get it. Thanks a lot ! :)